# Looking for a three panel css layout like this wordpress one

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templates, background-image

I love the Day Dream theme on Wordpress. http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/daydream/. I am having trouble making my one column page have a line design run vertically along the left and right edges. I am trying to center a background image on it. Is that the right way to go? If someone has seen a template like this for free I would take that too.

Comment: And you have tried what so far? Please show us your HTML and CSS that you have tried.

Comment: Also have you looked at how they have achieved that effect? Use Firebug for Firefox of hit F12 in Chrome to inspect the elements of a page. This is one of the best ways to dissect a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the blueprint CSS framework, its extremely helpful when dealing with layouts like this.

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

All you would need would be something like this if you where using it.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="span-8"></div>
 <div class="span-8"></div>
 <div class="span-8"></div>
</div>
```

In each of those columns you can add whatever you like, this isn't a fluid design though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to spoon feed the answer to this one. 5 minutes with [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for firefox or Use the [Elements Panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) in Chrome should give you enough insite into the page to create your own version of it. Both the HTML and CSS for this template are very simple.

Some starting points for Firebug:

- https://getfirebug.com/html
- https://getfirebug.com/css